# Is there Support?

Tags: installation

Do you provide support services to users? If so, what is the cost or cost of additional add-ons? I've heard that this is priced a-la-carte per submitted request

Comment: Curious where you heard "I've heard that this is priced a-la-carte per submitted request"?

Answer (score 5):

civicrm has a community of professionals who provide commercial support. We - Fuzion - are one such company. Others are listed at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

The Core Team also do paid work, though I think they focus on bigger improvements - see https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue.

If you are a 'member' then there is a discount for the Core Team work - https://civicrm.org/become-a-member

Community provided support includes

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com

https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/

Comment: Exactly. You can get some free support from sites such as this. Many of us who work with CiviCRM give a little back by helping to answer people's issues for free. But you may very well run into the need to have a paid person who knows CiviCRM who can do various work for you. There are a number of us out there who do this work at different levels. The link above has some, although there are smaller firms and such that aren't able to pay to be a sustaining contributor and aren't listed there.